# How to display an error message when the fields are not filled in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

how do we display an error message when input are not filled?
here is my code:

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <label>Enter your name</label>
        <input id="myName" type="text" placeholder="Your name here"><br>
        <label>enter your first name</label>
        <input id="myFirstName" type="text" placeholder="Your first name here"><br>
        <input id="myButton" type="button" value="submit">
       </form>
        <p id="mydisplay"></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

function myFunction(){
    var x = document.getElementById("myName").value + "<BR>" + document.getElementById("myFirtName").value ;
    if (x != ""){
        alert("Thank you fill in the fields")
    } else{
        document.getElementById("myDisplay").innerHTML = x;
    }
}

window.addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", myFunction);
});
```

yet I test the fields before but no error message is displayed to tell me that my input are empty.
on the other hand after that it shows me well what I mark in the input in the my page

Comment: You always add + "<BR>" to x so logically x is always != ""

Comment: x will never be an empty string as you have appended a br in there

Comment: there's a typo in your JavaScript: "myFirtName" instead of "myFirstName" (missing "s")

Comment: I see three issues. A typo "myFirtName" instead of "myFirstName" (missing "s"). The fact that you are always adding BR in your string makes it never empty even if the input fields are empty, Lastly... the form is submitted regardless because you are not preventing default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

Checks to see if either is blank.

```
function myFunction(){
    if (!document.getElementById("myName").value || !document.getElementById("myFirstName").value){
        alert("Thank you fill in the fields")
    } else{
        document.getElementById("myDisplay").innerHTML = x;
    }
}
```

Blank strings are not "truthy" in JavaScript.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Answer (score 0):

What about using The required Attribute? would be much easier, git it a try..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>The required Attribute</h2>
<p>The required attribute specifies that an input field must be filled out before submitting the form.</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari prior version 10.1.</p>

</body>
</html>
```